# How to efficiently transform narrow table into wide in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a narrow table with the following columns:
`<Customer ID> <Field ID> <Value>`, all of them are numbers.

I want to reshape this table into the wide format:

`<Customer ID> <Field1> <Field2> <Field3> ...`

I have a separate dictionary table `DIC_FIELDS` that translates Field ID into Field Name.

I work on EXADATA server. The narrow table has 2.5 billion records, and we have about 200 fields.

The obvious simple solution below badly fills up all temporary space on our EXADATA server.

```
create table WIDE_ADS as (
   CUSTOMERID
  ,max(case when FIELDID = 1 then VALUE end) as GENDER
  ,max(case when FIELDID = 2 then VALUE end) as AGE
  ,max(case when FIELDID = 3 then VALUE end) as EDUCATION
from NARROW_ADS
group by CUSTOMERID
);
```

We tried also a cleverer and manual method:

```
create index index1
      on SZEROKI_ADS(CUSTOMERID);


DECLARE
    rowidWide rowid;
    type tColNames is table of STRING(32000) index by pls_integer ;
    arrColNames tColNames;
    x_CustomerID number;
    strColName varchar2(32);
    strColvalue varchar2(32000);
    strSQL varchar2(200);
    lngCounter pls_integer;
    lngFieldID pls_integer;
BEGIN
    lngCounter := 0;
    -- we pre-load the dictionary arrColNames to speedup lookup.
    for DIC_EL in (select * from DIC_FIELDS order by FIELDID) LOOP
        lngFieldID := to_number(DIC_EL.FIELDID);
        arrColNames(lngFieldID) := DIC_EL.FIELDNAME;
    END LOOP;

    FOR NARROW_REC IN (SELECT * FROM NARROW_ADS where VALUE is not null ) LOOP 
        strColName := arrColNames(NARROW_REC.FIELDID);
        strColvalue := NARROW_REC.VALUE;
        x_IDKlienta := NARROW_REC.CUSTOMERID;
        BEGIN
            select rowid into rowidWide from WIDE_ADS
                where CUSTOMERID = NARROW_REC.CUSTOMERID;
            strSQL := 'update :1 set :2 = :3 where rowid = :4';
            execute immediate strSQL using WIDE_ADS, strColName, strColvalue, rowidWide;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                strSQL := 
                'insert into '|| WIDE_ADS ||' (CUSTOMERID, '|| strColName ||')
                 values 
                    (:1, :2)';
                execute immediate strSQL using  x_CustomerID, to_number(strColvalue) ;
        END;
        IF lngCounter=10000 THEN
            COMMIT;
            lngCounter:=0;
            dbms_output.put_line('Clik...');
        ELSE
            lngCounter:=lngCounter+1;
        END IF;    
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Although it doesn't take a temp, it fails miserably performance-wise; it processes 10 000 records in 50 sec - that is about 1000 times slower, then expected.

What can we do to speed up the process?

Comment: What version of Oracle? Can you use pivot (11g and later), and does that perform better than your manual case version? The data has to be held somewhere while it's transformed though, so I imagine temporary use might be similar. (I guess a supplementary question is whether you really need a new table, or could create a view of the pivoted data instead?)

Comment: PL/SQL `row-by-row` a.k.a. `slow-by-slow`. On top of that `dynamic sql` to make it even worse. Do it in SQL. To avoid high temp space usage, do it in chunks based on customer_id, of course that would consume a lot of sort_area_size, however, you would be able to perform the task in SQL.

Comment: @AlexPoole We use Oracle v 12 so we should be fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As Lalit comments, try to do it in chunks based on `CUSTOMERID`.

First, create a index on `CUSTOMERID` (if it does not exist):

```
CREATE INDEX INDNARROWADS ON NARROW_ADS(CUSTOMERID);
```

Second, we are going to create an auxiliary table to compute buckets based on `CUSTOMERID` (in this example we create 1000 buckets, 1 bucket will represent 1 block insert statement):

```
CREATE TABLE BUCKETS(MINCUSTOMER, MAXCUSTOMER, BUCKETNUM) AS
  SELECT MIN(CUSTOMERID), MAX(CUSTOMERID), BUCKET
    FROM (SELECT CUSTOMERID, 
                 WIDTH_BUCKET(CUSTOMERID, 
                              (SELECT MIN(CUSTOMERID) FROM NARROW_ADS),
                              (SELECT MAX(CUSTOMERID) FROM NARROW_ADS),
                              1000) BUCKET
            FROM NARROW_ADS)
    GROUP BY BUCKET;
```

You can use more/less buckets modifying the fourth argument of WIDTH_BUCKET function.

Third, create the `WIDE_ADS` table (the structure with no data). You should do it manually (with special attention on storage parameters) but you can also use your own query with a `WHERE` false condition:

```
create table WIDE_ADS as select
   CUSTOMERID
  ,max(case when FIELDID = 1 then VALUE end) as GENDER
  ,max(case when FIELDID = 2 then VALUE end) as AGE
  ,max(case when FIELDID = 3 then VALUE end) as EDUCATION
 from NARROW_ADS
 where 1=0;
```

Fourth, execute your query over each bucket (1 bucket means 1 insert statement):

```
BEGIN
  FOR B IN (SELECT * FROM BUCKETS ORDER BY BUCKETNUM) LOOP
     INSERT INTO WIDE_ADS  
       SELECT 
         CUSTOMERID
        ,max(case when FIELDID = 1 then VALUE end) as GENDER
        ,max(case when FIELDID = 2 then VALUE end) as AGE
        ,max(case when FIELDID = 3 then VALUE end) as EDUCATION
       FROM NARROW_ADS
       WHERE CUSTOMERID BETWEEN B.MINCUSTOMER AND B.MAXCUSTOMER
       GROUP by CUSTOMERID;
     COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

And finally, drop auxiliary table (and index if it is not necessary).

Oracle optimizer should use the index on `CUSTOMERID` to perform an "index range scan" over `NARROW_ADS`. So, each `INSERT` should find efficiently its corresponding interval.

Note that `WIDTH_BUCKETS` creates buckets based on uniform divisions over the  specified interval on `CUSTOMERID` (from min to max values). It does not create buckets based on uniform number of rows. And also note that `NARROW_ADS` must not be modified while this process is being executed.

As the PL/SQL block executes a `COMMIT` on each iteration and the loop iterates over buckets using the `BUCKETNUM` order, you can see how WIDE_ADS grows and which bucket is being processed (retrieving the max `CUSTOMERID` from `WIDE_ADS` and find its corresponding bucket on `BUCKETS` table).

If temporary space usage is to high, then increase the number of buckets (each insert will be smaller).